# Issues with tuneGrid parameter in random forest

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I've been dealing with some extremely imbalanced data and I would like to use stratified sampling to created more balanced random forests

Right now, I'm using the caret package, mainly to for tuning the random forests.
So I try to setup a tuneGrid to pass in the mtry and sampsize parameters into caret train method as follows.

```
mtryGrid <- data.frame(.mtry = 100),.sampsize=80)
rfTune<- train(x = trainX,
               y = trainY,
               method = "rf",
               trControl = ctrl,
               metric = "Kappa",
               ntree = 1000,
               tuneGrid = mtryGrid,
               importance = TRUE)
```

When I run this example, I get the following error

```
The tuning parameter grid should have columns mtry
```

I've come across discussions like [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/CARET-Any-way-to-access-other-tuning-parameters-td4658409.html) suggesting that passing in these parameters in should be possible.

On the other hand, this [page](http://topepo.github.io/caret/modelList.html) suggests that the only parameter that can be passed in is mtry

Can I even pass in sampsize into the random forests via caret?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like there is a bracket issue with your `mtryGrid`. Alternatively, you can also use `expand.grid` to give the different values of `mtry` you want to try.
By default the only parameter you can tune for a random forest is `mtry`. However you can still pass the others parameters to `train`. But those will have a fix value an so won't be tuned by `train`. But you can still ask to use a stratified sample in `train`. Below is how I would do, assuming that `trainY` is a boolean variable according which you want to stratify your samples, and that you want samples of size 80 for each category:

```
mtryGrid <- expand.grid(mtry = 100) # you can put different values for mtry
rfTune<- train(x = trainX,
               y = trainY,
               method = "rf",
               trControl = ctrl,
               metric = "Kappa",
               ntree = 1000,
               tuneGrid = mtryGrid,
               strata = factor(trainY),
               sampsize = c(80, 80), 
               importance = TRUE)
```

Comment: For some reason, I thought sampsize couldn't be passed into train().  Oh well.  Thanks!

Comment: @Garnieje, what is a good resource to know which parameters can you tune for each method (e.g., `mtry` for `rf`)?  I was thinking that I could add `ntree` and run into the same issue...

Comment: Nevermind, [I found it](http://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html#random-forest)

Comment: @toto_tico And if you don't want to read through the documentation:    `caret::modelLookup(model = "rf")`

Answer (score 0):

I doubt one can directly pass `sampsize` and `strata` to `train`. But from [here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html) I believe the solution is to use `trControl()`. That is,

```
mtryGrid <- data.frame(.mtry = 100),.sampsize=80)
rfTune<- train(x = trainX,
               y = trainY,
               method = "rf",
               trControl = trainControl(sampling=X),
               metric = "Kappa",
               ntree = 1000,
               tuneGrid = mtryGrid,
               importance = TRUE)
```

where `X` can be one of `c("up","down","smote","rose")`.